# How do I Convert ARGB value from string to colour?

Tags: delphi, gdi+, argb

I am trying to use the `MakeColor` method in the GDIPAPI unit but the conversion from `int` to `byte` is not returning me the correct value.

**Example**

```
var
    argbStr: string;
    A, R, G, B: Byte;
begin
    argbStr := 'ffffcc88';
    A := StrToInt('$' + Copy(AValue, 1, 2));
    R := StrToInt('$' + Copy(AValue, 3, 2));
    G := StrToInt('$' + Copy(AValue, 5, 2));
    B := StrToInt('$' + Copy(AValue, 7, 2));
    Result := MakeColor(A, R, G, B);
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two things.  First, what's your result type supposed to be?  Second, shouldn't the first Copy call say 1, not 0, as the first argument?

Comment: Also, where is GDIAPI from?  I don't have that unit in my Delphi 2010 installation.

Comment: @Mason, I mentioned the `MakeColor` method is in the GDIPAPI unit its part of GDI+...The return type is a TValue.

Comment: The return type of `MakeColor` is `ARGB`, not `TValue`. Perhaps that's the problem. What "correct value" did you expect to get, and what value did you get instead? What were the values of the intermediate variables?

Comment: @Rob, I understand that. I use TValue because the method is generic. I do the relevant casting when I am setting the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color components in your string are in the same order they would have in a `ARGB` value. Therefore, you don't need to separate the components before combining them with `MakeColor`. You can do the conversion directly:

```
function StringToARGB(const argbStr: string): GDIPAPI.ARGB;
begin
  Result := ARGB(StrToInt('$' + argbStr));
end;
```

The type-cast is necessary to suppress a range-checking error you'd get whenever the alpha component was greater than 127; `StrToInt` returns a signed integer, but `ARGB` is an unsigned type.

Comment: @Rob, even better! What about if I only had RBG? Would I just append `ff` to the string?

Comment: I guess you meant to write `StrToInt`, not `IntToStr`.

Comment: Yes. Or, if you want to make sure that any color you might get is fully, so this: `Result := AlphaMask or ARGB(StrToInt('$' + argbStr));`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type of `A, R, G, B` to be Integer seemed to fix the issue. It must be something to do with the casting between Integer -> Byte.